# Eloquent ORM - save record with 2 reference fields

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

If I create a comment like this:

```
$post->comments()->create(array('body' => 'Comment message'));
```

And I have the model on my post:

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->morphMany('Comment', 'shared_comments');
}
```

It fills the polymorphic relationship field between post and comment.

I also have the model on my comment:

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

How can I also fill the 'user_id' field in the comment table?

Comment: Just dropping this: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46607/laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just explicitly specify the user id in the array.

```
$post->comments()->create(array(
    'body' => 'Comment message',
    'user_id' => Auth::user()->id
));
```

Alternatively, you could create the comment and then insert the relationship with both the posts and users tables.

```
$post = Post::find($whatever);
$user = Auth::user()->id;

$comment = Comment::create(array(
    'body' => 'Comment message'
));

$post->comments()->insert($comment);
$user->comments()->insert($comment);
```

In Laravel 4, you would use `save($comment)` instead of `insert($comment)` for the last two lines. This is a breaking change from Laravel 3.

Comment: I was hoping for a with option that sort of works the opposite of doing a get with with()

Comment: The tricky thing here is that the comment belongs to both a post and user. Inserting one relationship is simple, but I don't think there's a shorter/cleaner way to do it with two.

Comment: I like this because it mimics a lot of my other code and is easier to read.  I need to check if this works with polymorphic relationships the same as belongs to and has many.  Marking answered.

Comment: One thing to note is that create may fail if some of these foreign keys are not nullable. You should be able to replace `Comment::create(array(/*params*/))` with `new Comment(array(/*params*/));` and then do `$comment->save()` at the end.